# Every irrational number is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers

Tags: functions, continuity

How can I use this fact to show that f(y)=y for every real number y, given that f is continuous

Comment: HINT: Every irrational number is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers.

Comment: Isn't every real number the limit if a sequence of rational numbers as well? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @123under: Yes, but it’s the irrational ones that matter here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$, $\forall x\in \Bbb{R}$

Notice that $g(q)=0$, $\forall q\in \Bbb{Q}$

Since $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$, it follows that $(*)$ $$g(x)\equiv0$$ $\forall x\in \Bbb{R}$, thus $$f(x)=x$$

$(*)$Indeed, this is a property for every $g\in D$, such that $g(d)=0\forall d\in D$, where $D$ is a dense subset of $\Bbb{R}$.

Let $x_0 \in \Bbb{R}$.

$D$ is dense, hence $\exists$ $(x_n)\subseteq D$ with $x_n\rightarrow x_0$

Since $g$ is continuous it follows that $$g(x_n)\rightarrow g(x_0)\Rightarrow \\0\rightarrow g(x_0)\Rightarrow\\ g(x_0)=0$$ as desired.